# SQL Time interval data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter data from table based on a start and end time and also a time interval
eg

```
2018-07-18 10:00:00  :  01    
2018-07-18 10:00:01  :  02
2018-07-18 10:00:02  :  03
2018-07-18 10:00:03  :  04
2018-07-18 10:00:04  :  05
2018-07-18 10:00:05  :  06
2018-07-18 10:00:06  :  07
2018-07-18 10:00:07  :  08
```

I want the data every 2 seconds to be displayed

```
2018-07-18 10:00:00  :  01
2018-07-18 10:00:02  :  03
2018-07-18 10:00:04  :  05
2018-07-18 10:00:06  :  07
```

Comment: Do you have data of every second like in the example above?

Comment: yes..but i want to filter it according to time interval

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server

You can do it as follows -

```
declare @datetime as table
( dt datetime)
declare @start as datetime = '2018-07-18 10:00:02  :  03'; --arbitrary - choose what you want
declare @end as datetime = '2018-07-18 10:00:06  :  07'; --arbitrary - choose what you want
insert into @datetime
 values
('2018-07-18 10:00:00  :  01')    
,('2018-07-18 10:00:01  :  02')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:02  :  03')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:03  :  04')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:04  :  05')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:05  :  06')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:06  :  07')
,('2018-07-18 10:00:07  :  08')
select * from @datetime
where 
dt>= @start and dt <=@end -- choose the condition you want
and datepart(SS,dt)%2 = 0 -- %2 is for 2 seconds; modify interval accordingly
```

Output

```
2018-07-18 10:00:02.003
2018-07-18 10:00:04.007
2018-07-18 10:00:06.007
```

Comment: That works for 2 seconds...But what if the user is going to enter time intervals randomly and what if i have to do the same in minutes

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2014.

Comment: `datepart(MINUTE,dt)%2 = 0` for minute. 

You can use this link for more details in this regard- [DatePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

If the user has to put an interval of say 5 minutes, the equation will look like this - 

`datepart(MINUTE,dt)%5 = 0`

Comment: If this time interval is supposed to be arbitrary. I will suggest you to use dynamic sql.

Comment: actually, this does help but my problem persists as the interval should be applicable from start time and the user can enter any time.eg he enters 12:01:00 as start and interval is 3 minutes then the readings shud be for 12:01:00 ; 12:04:00 ; 12:07:00 etc....The logging of data is every second

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    DECLARE @interval INT=2;
    DECLARE @start AS DATETIME = '2018-07-18 10:00:00  :  03';



    DECLARE @datetime AS TABLE ( dt DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @datetime
    VALUES
    ('2018-07-18 10:00:00  :  01')    
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:01  :  02')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:02  :  03')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:03  :  04')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:04  :  05')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:05  :  06')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:06  :  07')
    ,('2018-07-18 10:00:07  :  08')


    ;WITH cte
    AS
    (
     SELECT * 
     FROM @datetime
     WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,dt,101),120)=CONVERT(CHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,@start,101),120)

        UNION ALL

     SELECT  t1.*
     FROM @datetime t1
     JOIN cte t2 ON CONVERT(CHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,t1.dt,101),120) =
            DATEADD(ss,@interval,CONVERT(CHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,t2.dt,101),120))
    )

    SELECT * FROM cte
```

Note: ***CONVERT(CHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,@Start,101),120***) is used to discard milliSeconds Part in Comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for each pair of seconds, I would suggest using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over
                 (partition by dateadd(second,
                                       2 * (datediff(second, 0, dtcol) / 2),
                                       0
                                      )
                  order by dtcol
                 ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```